# Firebase Token Refresh on Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

We have an app then a Cloud Function as well that serves HTTP request. To secure and target the user data, we used the token generated from client/app then use it as a query parameter to HTTP request.

Client/App (Java)

```
firebaseUser.getIdToken(true).addOnSuccessListener(getTokenResult -> //HTTP here with Volley where getTokenResult.getToken() is one of the query parameters.
```

Server/Cloud Function

```
// idToken comes from the client app
        return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.query.idToken)
            .then(function (decodedToken) {

                var uid = decodedToken.uid;
                console.log("User verified: " + uid);
```

Everything works fine but as I recall token have expiration maybe after an hour, so my question is how can we manage token refresh once it gets expired on Cloud Function side since we do not want to repeatedly refresh it in client side?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK automatically refreshes the ID token behind the scenes. In fact, you don't have to (and probably shouldn't here from the looks of it) pass `true` into `getIdToken()` as it will return a valid token even when you pass `false`.

While it may be possible to refresh the token on the server, it is pretty uncommon. I strongly recommend that you leave the token refresh to the client-side SDK, and simply **use** the token on the server to verify the user.

So more concretely: just pass `false` into `getIdToken(false)` and leave it to the Firebase SDK to handle the refreshing of the ID token behind the scenes.

```
firebaseUser.getIdToken(false).addOnSuccessListener(getTokenResult...
```

Comment: Doing this, does it automatically trigger addOnSuccessListener just like ListenerRegistration for Cloud Firestore do whenever the token gets refresh or I need to call `firebaseUser.getIdToken(false)` manually and wait for success callback every time I need to update the token?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there, but the `addOnSuccessListener` in your code gets called the exact same way in both cases.  You should call `firebaseUser.getIdToken(false)` each time you when you need to pass the token to your server-side code.